# What is the cancel Build short key for sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Note the `ctrl+break` is **not work**, can I assign my own *keyboard shortcuts for sublime*??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it: `Preferences > Key Binding`